# Can liveagent.addcustomdetail API method dynamically handle different data scenarios

Tags: liveagent, servicecloud

Background and Use Case:

Currently, we are implementing LiveAgent functionality on one of our external website supporting some 22 countries. The Chat requestor 'selects' a country (say Australia) from a 'drop down field' and the 'chat button' (online/offline) corresponding to that country is displayed (Yes, we have a dedicated buttons for each country/region).

Pre-Chat form launches, the chat requestor fills out a form with Name, Email, Company & Product information and then connects with our agents (country specific).

Requirement:

The requirement is showing the country value selected by the chat requestor on the external web page. And passing on that information over to Salesforce Liveagent Console and subsequently in the Chat transcript so that it is visible to agent during chat session and for subsequent reporting purposes.

Challenge:

Even though we are able to pass the initial Country value selected by the chat requestor with the combination of 'JS' and 'liveagent.addcustomdetail()' API.

However, we are facing issues for the following scenario:

1. Identical chat button id: if a chat requestor change the country selection from Australia to (lets say) New Zealand [Note: Australia and New Zealand have identical chat button id and same agents supporting the region]. Then, chat button is visible but 'liveagent.addcustomdetail()' API is not updating to new country value instead its still showing  the original selection i.e. 'Australia' since that country value is already loaded when 'Liveagent.init()' runs
2. Different chat button id: if a chat requestor change the country selection from Australia to (lets say) Korea [note: Australia and Korea are supported by different agents and as such different chat buttons]. Then, chat button is not visible to the chat requestor. Again this is due to 'Liveagent.init()'

Our understanding:

DOM is already loaded with init function when the page loads, when we make the first country selection. It do not take into consideration any subsequent changes to the Country drop down field thereof.

Thus the question is, can liveagent.addcustomdetail dynamically handle different data scenario rather than capturing the data value which is provided when the Liveagent.inti API loads? If yes how?

UPDATE:  Here is the sample code that I created for testing purpose (this is not the original code though). hope this will give you a

```
    <html>
    <head></head>  
    <body>

    <!-- START Deployment Code Chat button package ---->
     <script type='text/javascript' src='https://c.la2cs.salesforceliveagent.com/content/g/js/31.0/deployment.js'></script>
   <!-- END   Deployment Code Chat button package ---->


    <script>    

function run() {
    document.getElementById("cntry1").value = document.getElementById("Ultra").value;
        liveagent.addCustomDetail('Country',  document.getElementById("cntry1").value).saveToTranscript('Country__c');
        liveagent.init('https://d.la2cs.salesforceliveagent.com/chat', '572R00000008OPa', '00DR0000001tHI1');
}

function countryname() {
    var cname1 = document.getElementById("cntry1").value;
    alert (" test :: "+ cname1);
}
     </script>

   <!----------------Code added for testing purpose ---------------->
  <br></br>
 <!-- In the actual code, I have separate div block for each of the countries below.  For testing purpose, i have calling just the Malayasia chat button regardless of the country selection   --->
 <select id="Ultra" onchange="run(); ">  <!--Call run() function-->
     <option value="">Select</option>
     <option value="Australia">AU</option>
     <option value="Indonesia">ID</option>
     <option value="Malaysia">MY</option>
     <option value="Korea">KR</option>
 </select><br><br>

 <input type="hidden" id="cntry1"  value="USA" name="cntry1">

 <!----------------------------------------------------------------->

   <!--- Start of Main Chat code --->
     <a id="liveagent_button_online_XXXX0000000XXXX" href="javascript://Chat" style="display: none;" onclick="liveagent.startChat('XXXX0000000XXXX'); countryname();">Chat!</a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     if (!window._laq) { window._laq = []; }
      window._laq.push(function(){liveagent.showWhenOnline('XXXX0000000XXXX', document.getElementById('liveagent_button_online_XXXX0000000XXXX'));
     liveagent.showWhenOffline('XXXX0000000XXXX', document.getElementById('liveagent_button_offline_XXXX0000000XXXX'));});</script>

    <div id="liveagent_button_offline_XXXX0000000XXXX" style="display: none;">
   <!-- Failover to Alternate chat button   -->
    <!--    START   Alternate Chat Code for APJ-ISO-EN Group --->

           <a id="liveagent_button_online_XXXX0000000XXXX" href="javascript://Chat" style="display: none;" onclick="liveagent.startChat('XXXX0000000XXXX'); countryname();">APJ-EN is Online</a>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            if (!window._laq) { window._laq = []; }
            window._laq.push(function(){liveagent.showWhenOnline('XXXX0000000ZZZz',document.getElementById('liveagent_button_online_XXXX0000000ZZZz'));
           liveagent.showWhenOffline('573R0000000CaZz', document.getElementById('liveagent_button_offline_XXXX0000000ZZZz'));});          </script>

                <div id="liveagent_button_offline_XXXX0000000ZZZz" style="display: none;">
                Sorry we missed you! Please try again later. Thank You</div>

     <!--   END     Alternate Chat Code for APJ-ISO-EN Group --->                       
   </div>

    <!--- End of Main Chat Code --->
     </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this As I have same scenario ..?

Comment: Yes, however, we tweak the process a little bit. Instead of showing the countries drop down on the external portal. We moved that option/field (a required input) on the Live agent pre-chat form.  The chatvisitor picks the country value... we pass the value to the salesforce console/stores etc. I was unable to resolve the original issue, since we can't modify the inti.js salesforce live agent chat libraries.